# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') shows in console

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

This error shows in the console and I can not find the solution to solve it. I have not even used "toString" in the app. I think there is problem in the Row section. Because every time I delete the the Row and the elements in it, the error disappear.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import millify from 'millify';
    import { Typography, Row, Col, Statistic } from 'antd';
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

    import { useGetCryptosQuery } from '../services/cryptoApi';
    import Cryptocurrencies from './Cryptocurrencies';
    import News from './News';
    import Loader from './Loader';

    const { Title } = Typography;  

    const Homepage = () => {
    const { data, isFetching } = useGetCryptosQuery(10);
    const globalStats = data?.data?.stats;

    if (isFetching) return <Loader />;


    return (
    <>
      <Title level={2} className="heading">Global Crypto Stats</Title>
      <Row>
        <Col span={12}>
          <Statistic title='Total Cryptocurrencies' value={globalStats?.total} />
        </Col>
        <Col span={12}>
          <Statistic title='Total Exchanges' value={millify(globalStats?.totalExchanges)} />
        </Col>
        <Col span={12}>
          <Statistic title='Total Market Cap' value={millify(globalStats?.totalMarketCap)} />
        </Col>
        <Col span={12}>
          <Statistic title='Total 24h Volume' value={millify(globalStats?.total24hVolume)} />
        </Col>
        <Col span={12}>
          <Statistic title='Total Markets' value={millify(globalStats?.totalMarkets)} />
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <div className="home-heading-container">
        <Title level={2} className="home-title">Top 10 Cryptos In The World</Title>
        <Title level={3} className="show-more"><Link to="/cryptocurrencies">Show more</Link></Title>
      </div>
      <Cryptocurrencies simplified />
      <div className="home-heading-container">
        <Title level={2} className="home-title">Latest Crypto News</Title>
        <Title level={3}><Link to="/news">Show more</Link></Title>
      </div>
      <News simplified />
    </>
  );
};
export default Homepage;
```

Comment: What else does the error say?  What is the stack trace for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appear to be a bug in the `millify` package. Specifically, `millify` takes a value and converts it to a string. While doing this, it first attempts to parse the string value. They correctly check to see if the value is a number or not, but they fail to check if the value actually exists:

[Problematic code](https://github.com/izolate/millify/blob/8cc295de03374101feddcbe2a002834dbf609a58/lib/utils.ts#L4-L14)

Reproduced here for commenting:

```
export function parseValue(value: number): number {
  const val: number = parseFloat(value.toString());

  if (isNaN(val)) {
    throw new Error(`Input value is not a number`);
  }
  if (val > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER || val < Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER) {
    throw new RangeError("Input value is outside of safe integer range");
  }
  return val;
}
```

The error is on the first line, since `value` might not exist, and calling `.toString` on an `undefined` value will give you the error you are seeing.

The ideal fix would be for `millify` to solve it on their end and push a package update, but that won't solve your immediate issue. To solve your immediate issue, make sure you never pass `undefined` or `null` to `millify`, so:

```js
// Change this
millify(globalStats?.totalExchanges)

// To this
millify(globalStats?.totalExchanges || 0)
```

Comment: I had [submitted an issue](https://github.com/izolate/millify/issues/28) about this to `millify`, though the package does not appear to be actively maintained, so really, I would liekly recommend to stop using it.

Comment: Maintainer here: millify is intentionally strict about input value types. I've published the proposed fix in `v4.0.1`, but that will *still* error if you send in a `null` or `undefined` value, just with a different error. For better or worse, the package requires you send in a number type, so solving it on the consumer side is preferred. I'd be open to changing that, but that would be a breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

Maintainer of `millify` here. It is strict with values you send to it, so you need to ensure any `undefined` values have a fallback number.

You can accomplish this with the nullish coalescing operator:

```js
<Statistic title='Total Exchanges' value={millify(globalStats?.totalExchanges ?? 0)} />
```

NOTE: in previous versions, it would have thrown an error without the fallback. However, I've just published [v5.0.0](https://github.com/izolate/millify/releases/tag/v5.0.0) which now gracefully handles these nullish values without throwing an error.